# How to load Subgurim GMap object in razor(MVC3/4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, subgurim-maps

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to load a Google Map on my page.

I'm using [Subgurim](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/) lib and already have the map object, but I don't know how to load it into the page.

Here's what I got so far:

```
 @model Subgurim.Controles.GMap
 @{    
      ViewBag.Title = "Pesquisa Carona";
 }
<h2>PesquisaCarona</h2>
<h4>Diga o endereço</h4>
<input type="text" name="txEndereco" />
<input type="submit" />
<cc1:GMap ID="googleMap" runat="server" /> <!-- This doesnt work!!!--!>
```

I know that normally I would add the map accessing it directly like:

For the serverside:

```
GMap1.addGMarker(oMarker);
```

And for the page:

```
<cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="300px" />
```

But with MVC I can't do that.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to the the basic example to work using .NET 4.5, MVC 5 (razor), GMaps 4.1.0.6, and Visual Studio 2013 by rendering an ascx user control as a partial in the cshtml.  Here is what I did to get it to work:

- Add the Subgurim.Maps package from NuGet.
- Add an ascx control: In my case it was Gmap.ascx placed in the same folder as the cshtml I wanted to use.  Your code should end up looking like the following:
- In the ascx:

  > ```
  > <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Gmap.ascx.cs" Inherits="YourApp.Views.Gmap" %>  
  > <%@ Register Assembly="GMaps" Namespace="Subgurim.Controles" TagPrefix="gmaps" %>
  > <form id="form1" runat="server">
  >     <gmaps:GMap
  >         ID="GMap1"
  >         runat="server"
  >         Width="500px"
  >         Height="250px"
  >         EnableViewState="False" />
  > </form>
  > ```
- In the ascx.cs:

  > ```
  > namespace YourAPP.Views
  > {
  >     using System;
  >     using System.Drawing;
  >     using System.Web.Mvc;
  >
  >     public partial class Gmap : ViewUserControl
  >     {
  >         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  >         {
  >             GMap1.enableDragging = false;
  >             GMap1.Language = "en";
  >             GMap1.BackColor = Color.White;
  >             GMap1.Key = "YOUR GOOGLE KEY";
  >             GMap1.CommercialKey="YOUR COMMERCIAL KEY";
  >         }
  >     }
  > }
  > ```
- In the cshtml:

  > @Html.Partial("Gmap")

** A couple of things to note:

- The form tag in the ascx is required it won't work without it.
- The control needs to inherit from ViewUserControl instead of UserControl to work with razor.
- Make sure you have your keys for the control (Google, Commercial).  See the control site for details on those.
- If you didn't put the control in the same folder as your cshtml you will need to adjust the path given to the Partial helper.

Thank you to:

- The subgurim forums for the last bit about needing the form tags and the basic example.
- [How to display WebForms .ascx as partial view in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328835/how-to-display-webforms-ascx-as-partial-view-in-mvc-3) for how to load an ascx into a razor view.
- If I left anything out please go easy this is my first one.

I hope this helps - Cheers,

Anker

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.

On my project (made with MVC3) I've added a partial view in aspx engine (the rest of my website is with razor). I followed the subgurim tutorial site. Then I added the google api key  but I get a gray rectangle even if everything seems ok! 
Then I found this post on google: http://it.googlemaps.subgurim.net/Foro/general-discussions-perm5956-5963.aspx

:(

Comment: A possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359793/web-forms-within-an-asp-net-mvc-project

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of the project and we are working on a new version suitable for MVC (Razor or other view engine of choice). I'll update this response when it's ready for production.

Comment: Did this ever make it to production?

Comment: I don't think so, and I don't think will ever be. I left the project some time ago but there has not been much activity since then. Sorry.