# How to display WebForms .ascx as partial view in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. In this application, I would like to display an old WebForms user control (.ascx/.ascx.cs) in an overlay in my new MVC razor app as a partial view. I cant find anything about doing this on the web. Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so point me to some documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is very bad practice to do such a thing. However this could be achieved by the following code:

```
@Html.Partial("_Foo")
```

Then in your `_Foo` partial view, you could have the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="SomeAssembly" Namespace="SomeNs" TagName="foo" %>

<foo:SomeControl runat="server" ID="fooControl" />
```

Hope this helps. Have a look at this question:

- [MVC 3: Add usercontrol to Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317317/mvc-3-add-usercontrol-to-razor-view)

Answer (score 3):

The long answer involves 'yes you can, but....'

The short answer is, you shouldn't.

Without knowing the specifics of your .ascx file, you can render a partial using

```
@Html.Partial(PageName)
```

But, if you have any server controls they will not work. MVC doesn't support the same kind of call back control state functionality. So, you are using any thing resembling

```
<asp:Button runat=server />
```

then you're far better off re-factoring your partial.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar.
I've found these links that might help you.

http://www.codemag.com/article/1009061

[How do I render a remote ReportViewer aspx page in MVC4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422124/how-do-i-render-a-remote-reportviewer-aspx-page-in-mvc4)

[How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view)